# Best word to describe assesing value of a project

Tags: nouns, technical

I am a web developer, I often work with clients who like to know how much my work will cost them. The problem is - I am not a native English speaker and I need to tell them that I evaluated the price to be "x" dollars. I need to describe this process with one word.

Up until now we used the word "quote", but I guess it's incorrect.

Examples:

- Could you give me a quote for this project?
- Message me with your suggested quote.

I need a word to replace "quote" for those sentences to be correct. I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "quote" here; that's the one we'd usually use for an estimated cost of a service.

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnClifford. I appreciate ths feedback. I asked one more question in the comment section of an answer from MorganFR to clarify one problem I have with using the word "quote". Would you be so kind to take a look there and express your opinion?

Comment: As MorganFR said, when it's you (plural) who does the price estimate, it's "our quote" from your perspective, yes.

Comment: @JohnClifford Thank you, I am very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the words "estimate" or "price estimate", but "quote" works just as well.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Could you tell me one more thing? When I tell our client that he will recieve our quote for his project this afternoon, is "our quote" correct in that meaning? Does the quote become "our(s)" when it's us who does the price estimate?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Amazing help, thank you very much, sir (I need to wait a few minutes before I am able to accept the answer).

Comment: @Pe-Ter - For a formal proposal, you may use the expressions "financial offer" or "price declaration".

Answer (score -1):

A long time ago, when projects were done more formally, we used to produce a [feasibility study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasibility_study) early in the project. This sounds like the exact thing you describe.

EDIT: I see I answered the title of your question rather than the question itself. The title refers to "value" whereas the question is about quotes or estimations.

Comment: Assessing the practicality of a project isn't the same thing as telling a client your estimate of what it'll cost.

Comment: I still use feasibility studies in my projects, but it's not just about the price, but also the technology, the ambition, the pros and cons of different solutions (SWOT), the impact on the existing solutions and much more.